# Xamarin.Forms. How to add views on top of map, but right on the defined lat/lng position?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Currently i am developing a taxi app. But got to the point where i need to put some views on top of the map that will move when i move me map. I am wondering how it is possible to do it using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps package. The inbuilt "Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromView()" won't work for me because i need a view that consists of two or more clickable parts + i don't want the views to overlap. Adding a picture of what i need to achieve. Any help would be appreciated
[Here is the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKIFA.jpg)

Comment: Hi ,Welcome to SO ! Do you mean the plus image view right on the info window ?

Comment: Well, to be more specific those objects aren't info windows, they are separate views somehow placed on the screen right where they needed to be placed in the correct lat and lng position. I am looking more for a way to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xamarin.Forms.Maps? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/

This component makes it easier to work as you need.

In xaml file you need add this code:

>

```
<ContentView Content="{Binding Map}"/>
```

And in your viewModel add this code:

>

```
Map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(1)));
```

To add pins, add this:

>

```
 var pin = new Pin
           {
              Type = PinType.Place,
              Address = String.Empty,
              Label = item.Name,
              Position = new Position(item.Geometry.Location.Lat, item.Geometry.Location.Lng),
           };

pin.InfoWindowClicked += async (s, args) => { await PinClicked((Pin)s); };
                                    Map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

You can create a custom renderer for the Map control, which displays a native map with a customized pin and a customized view of the pin data on each platform.

Refer to this document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin#creating-the-custom-map

**Android** :

Custom the `MapPlusInfo.xml` in android native can achieve that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InfoWindowTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="InfoWindowTitle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InfoWindowSubtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="InfoWindowSubtitle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/InfoWindowButton"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/plus" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The renderer code in Android :

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
{
    List<CustomPin> customPins;

    public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);

        NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);

    }

    protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
    {
        var marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
        marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
        marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
        marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
        return marker;
    }

    void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
        {
            var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
    var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            Android.Views.View view;

            var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapPlusInfo, null);
                var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);
                if (infoSubtitle != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
                }

                return view;
            }
            else
            {
                //view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
            }


        }
        return null;
    }

    CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the problem is that as i understand the code and google maps api only one info window will be shown at a time. I am more looking of a way to somehow translate the lat lng point in to screen pixels in x/y and then somehow place a view in that x/y. Is it possible?

Comment: @Mr.Onion It seems not possible , as google maps api only one info window . But I'm interesting about why need a separate view to achieve that .

Comment: I need to get the pixels in order to place my views directly in that position on the map. But i need a view, not a pin or an info window - so i will have more control and do whatever i want with that view

Comment: @Mr.Onion Okey ,if Info window contains many controls , one inside is a plus Button  . When you click that button ,also can do your want . The button click event is independent of info window clicked .Why need an another separate view ?

Comment: Because i need to show several info windows at the same time. Imagine i have 4 points on my taxi route. I need to show all the addresses of these 4 points

Comment: @Mr.Onion  I think you wanted to add a waypoint function on the navigation route .

Comment: @Mr.Onion Okey , I think it should be possible . But now no solution for this , if found will update here later.

Comment: Waypoints are implemented. I only need this lat/lng to x/y conversion

Comment: Right now i found that we can use  
 var projection = NativeMap.Projection;
projection.ToScreenLocation( mypoint)
in the map renderer. But how to pass mypoint to the renderer? Maybe u know? I guess, because your answer is proficient in renderers)

Comment: @Mr.Onion Awesome !

Comment: @Mr.Onion If want to pass point to the renderer , you can refer to this doc . Defining parameters for custom map , then you can use them in renderer .

Comment: Can u post an example, please? I want to pass a lat,lng  dynamcially to the renderer and get a Point in return in the shared code. How to do this?

Comment: @Mr.Onion I will have a try , if achieve that will update in answer .

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I will do some research too

Comment: @Mr.Onion Hi , Bindable properties can used to pass to native code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties  . But not understanding return in shared code .